# Minimizable JFrame that stays on top of main application window

Tags: swing, jframe, jdialog, z-order, always-on-top

My apps pops up a dialog. Users usually want to switch back and forth between this dialog and the application window for a period of time. I want this dialog to stay on top, so that it doesn't get hidden behind the main application window. But at the same time I want the dialog to have a minimize button so that it can get out of the way if it's not needed for a while.

Here is what I've tried:

- use a modeless JDialog - the dialog stays in front  nicely, but it doesn't not have a minimize button, and it doesn't have its own taskbar button either
- use a JFrame - the dialog now has a minimize button and its own taskbar button, but when the main window gets focus the dialog is hidden behind it.
- use a JFrame and add WindowListener.windowDeactivated() { this.toFront() } on the dialog. The problem with this is that toFront() also sets the focus, so that you get a weird focus flickering effect.
- use a JFrame with setAlwaysOnTop - this is the neaerest solution, but now the window will stay on top of all other applications, not just my application.

It would be easy if toFront just brought the JFrame to the front without changing the focus, but unfortunately that is not the case. Is there another way to change JFrame Z-order?

edit: It just occurred to me that if there were an easy way to "roll-up" a JDialog, i.e. minimize it but not to the taskbar, that would solve my problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Why not listen for the focusGained event in the frame and then use setZOrder/toFront on the dialog at that point? (Not sure this will work but worth a shot).

Comment: I haven't found a setZOrder() method anywhere. I'll give it a try with toFront.