# Is it possible to allow a JFrame to be focused without bringing it to the front every time?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, focus, always-on-top

I am trying to keep a certain JFrame on top of only *one* other JFrame, not all JFrames and JDialogs. Thus, I have jFrame1 and jFrame2. I want jFrame2 to always stay on top of jFrame1 even if I click buttons and do other things on jFrame1. However, if jFrame1 launches a dialog box, I do **not** want that dialog box to be hidden behind jFrame2. So, setting the "Always on Top" property for jFrame2 is not sufficient, since I want jFrame2 to only stay on top of jFrame1, not every frame and dialog.

So, that leads to my question: is it possible in Java to focus a JFrame (jFrame1) by clicking on it or however it happens, without simultaneously bringing it to the front (and thus covering jFrame2)? Essentially, I would like to do the opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788953/is-it-possible-to-bring-jframe-to-front-but-not-focus). I have tried a couple of solutions. One does not work and the other is nonideal.

My first attempt involved overriding the deprecated show() method in my jFrame1 so that it would not call the toFront() method. This did not work because, I presume, the show() method never gets called when a JFrame gains focus. My attempts to track down the location in the Java source code where any kind of toFront() or similar call is made when focus is gained did not yield any results. I am not sure where the "send to front" behavior is being called from when the focus is gained.

My second attempt works for what I want it to do, but has a nonideal side effect. This second solution involved implementing a WindowFocusListener on jFrame1 and then filling the
windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) method with the following code, where shouldAlwaysBeOnTop() is simply the getter for a flag that indicates when I want this behavior to happen:

```
public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
    if (jFrame2.shouldAlwaysBeOnTop()) {
        jFrame2.toFront();
    }
}
```

This is basically [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480836/minimizable-jframe-that-stays-on-top-of-main-application-window?rq=1), and it does what I want it to do, but it involves first having the jFrame2 window be very briefly not shown (because it loses focus) and then very quickly shown again (because I call toFront() on it above)). This causes the jFrame2 window to "flash" or "blink" really fast every time jFrame1 is clicked on. Although otherwise this works how I want, the flashing behavior is not desirable. (When a dialog is displayed from jFrame1, then jFrame2 momentarily disappears until that dialog is dealt with and closed by the user. Then jFrame2 reappears. I am fine with this behavior but it is not necessary for jFrame2 to disappear in this instance - I am simply indifferent to it in this case).

So, is there a better way that I can have jFrame2 always be on top of jFrame1 while still being able to interact with jFrame1 and let it show dialog boxes that aren't covered by jFrame2 (whether or not the dialog box is on top of jFrame2 momentarily or jFrame2 momentarily disappears)?

Comment: *I am trying to keep a certain JFrame on top of only one other JFrame,* - the second JFrame should be a `non modal JDialog` (not a frame) and you specify the frame as the parent of the dialog.

Comment: Yes, that behavior is exactly what I want with respect to the specific functionality I mentioned in my question; however, I should have mentioned that I ruled that solution out from the beginning because, when using the JDialog, I lose certain features of the JFrame that I want to retain, such as the ability to minimize the window and have it be present on the task bar or have it go to back if desired. As my "shouldAlwaysBeOnTop()" method from above indicates, I only want this behavior to happen some of the time, not all of the time when jFrame2 is open. That's the tricky part.

Comment: A JFrame functions independently of other JFrames, that is why each frame appears on the task bar. Also if you make on frame "always on top" then it will always be on top (even if you click on the other frame). At least this is how it works using JDK11 on Windows 10. Post your [mre] demonstrating your problem. It takes about 10 lines of code to demonstrate using 2 frames.